# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . jQuery.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

For one reason or an another, i simply can't make the jQuery.get work.

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
rnjesus.html:56

The lines in question:

```
    jQuery.get("szamok.txt", function(data){
        frn = data;
    });
```

Complete code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RNJESUS</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="rnjesus.ico">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    </head>

    <body background="rnjesus.jpg" style="background-size: 100%" text="white">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <p align="center"> Üdvözlégy a félkész szerencsejáték szimulátorban. <br>
                    4 dologra lehet fogadni: 50 alatt, felett és ezen belül páros vagy páratlan.<br>
                    A Random Number Geisus (RNJézus) kisorsol neked egy számot 0 és 100 között. <br>
                    10 vagy az alatt, 90 vagy a felett, és kereken 50-nél a "ház" nyer. <br>
                    Jó játékot, és ne felejtkezz el imátkozzni RNJesushoz.<br>
    </p>

    <p align="center">
        Mennyivel akarsz beszállni?<br>
        <input type="number" min="1" name="fogcredit">
        <button onclick="bevitel()"> Bevitel</button>
        <button onclick="otvenalatt()">Fogadás: 50 alatt.</button>
        <button onclick="otvenfelett()">Fogadás: 50 felett.</button>
        <button id="start" onclick="jesus()"> My body is ready </button>
    </p>
    <h1 align="center" id="warning"></h1>
    <div align="center" id="creditcount"></div>
    <div align="center" id="time"></div>
    <div align="center" id="szam"></div>
    <div align="center" id="otven"></div>
    <div align="center" id="paratlan"></div>
    <h2 align="center" id="nyeremeny" ></h2>

    <p align="center">
    <button onclick="memes()">GIMME MEMES MOTHERFUCKER (200 credit)</button><br>
    <a href="succ.html" id="succ"><p align="center"></p></a>
    </p>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        var otvenvar;
        var nyeremenycredit;
        var credit = 100
        var szam
        var otvenvar
        var fogbevitel
        var fogadas
        var nyeremenycredit
        var credit
        var ido = 10
        var szam
        var 


        jQuery.get("szamok.txt", function(data){
            frn = data;
        });


        function memes(){
            if (credit < 200){
                document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = ("BROKE NIGGA");
            }

            if (credit > 200){
                document.getElementById("succ").innerHTML = ("I'll suck you in a second...");
                window.location.href = "suffni.myddns.me:10203/succ.html"
            }
        }

        function bevitel(){
        fogadas = document.getElementsByName("fogcredit")[0].value;
        }

        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
        function otvenfelett(){
        otvenvar = 1;
        }
        function otvenalatt(){
        otvenvar = 0;

        }
        setInterval(function jesus(){
            if (credit > fogadas || credit == fogadas){

                jQuery.get("szamok.txt", function(data){
                    frn = data
                })
                document.getElementById('szam').innerHTML = ("Szám: " +frn);
                credit = credit - fogadas;
                nyeremenycredit = 0
                document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = ("");

                if (frn < 11){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ('The house always wins.');
                    document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Mivel a ház nyert, nem számít hogy páros vagy pártalan.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                }

                if (frn > 89){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("The house always wins.");
                    document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Mivel a ház nyert, nem számít hogy páros vagy pártalan.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                }

                if (frn == 50){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("The house always wins.");
                    document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Mivel a ház nyert, nem számít hogy páros vagy pártalan.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                }

                if (frn > 10 && frn < 50){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("50 alatt nyert.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);

                    if (otvenvar == 0){
                        nyeremenycredit = fogadas * 2;
                        credit = credit + nyeremenycredit;
                        document.getElementById("nyeremeny").innerHTML = ("Nyertél " + fogadas + " creditet.");
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                    if (frn % 2 == 0){
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ('Páros szám nyert.');
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                    else{
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ('Páratlan szám nyert.');
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                }

                if (frn < 90 && frn > 50){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("50 felett nyert.");
                    if (otvenvar == 1){
                        nyeremenycredit = fogadas * 2;
                        credit = credit + nyeremenycredit;
                        document.getElementById("nyeremeny").innerHTML = ("Nyertél " + fogadas + " creditet.");
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                    if (frn % 2 == 0){
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Páros szám nyert.");
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                    else{
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Páratlan szám nyert.");
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                }
            }

            if (credit < fogadas){
            document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = ("BROKE NIGGA");
            }
        }, 10000);

        setInterval(function(){
            if (ido > 0){
                ido = ido - 1
                documet.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ("Ennyi idő van hátra= " + ido )
            }
            if (ido == 0){
                documet.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ("Sorsolás megtörtént.")
                ido = 10
            }
        }, 1000);
        }
    //]]>
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

No, it isn't from jsfiddle. Its all written by hand.
Any idea?
Edit 1: Included full. code. Yes, i know there are unused vars. They are leftovers that will be used again.

Comment: insufficient information

Comment: What should i include then? Rest of the code works fine, but in the moment i put this in, it just dies.

Comment: I didn't find any error in your code. That's why I asked more info. put your get method another js file and try.

Comment: @CsabaKiss - the context that this code sits within is important to diagnosing the issue. Ideally please provide the minimal cut-down code that illustrates the issue. You will find that you get a much more fruitful response. There is a fable about a blind man being allowed to feel only the tail of an elephant and then guess what animal it is....you are making  us play a similar game.

Comment: @AndyRay please check the response time before comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
    var 


    jQuery.get("szamok.txt", function(data){
        frn = data;
    });
```

Remove the empty `var`.

Comment: I am dumb. Thanks.

Comment: @CsabaKiss That's why I asked for the full code.